# Development container mounted source dependency mismatch in .NET Core app

Tags: docker, asp.net-core

I am trying to set up a development environment for a new ASP.NET Core application.  Ideally, I would like to run the application in a container locally to ensure dev/prod parity.  However, I'm currently experiencing some difficulty with this due to the fact that the binary dependencies are different on my host (mac) than the container.  Since I've mounted the base app directory in the container, when the container restores the dependencies it overwrites the local ones, which must be a different binary.  This causes my IDE to lose Intellisense and any semblance of understanding the files, and errors appear everywhere in the codebase.

I am using the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.0-sdk
WORKDIR /app/UnmIdi.Consilio.Api

# copy everything and build the project
# RUN dotnet restore UnmIdi.Consilio.Api/*.csproj
ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT Development
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://[::]:8000
CMD ./run.sh
```

where `run.sh` contains:

```
#!/bin/sh
dotnet restore
dotnet watch run
```

When i start the container for development, I'm using the following docker-compose.yml setup:

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: ./Backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.development
    ports:
      - "5555:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./Backend/:/app
  frontend:
    ...
  postgres:
    ...
  redis:
    ...
```

Is there a way to use this sort of setup and retain the local dependencies so my IDE will function properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can separate binaries compiled inside the container and in the host by moving the `obj/` and `bin/` directories into different locations. You can do this by overriding the MSBuild properties "BaseIntermediateOutputPath" and "OutputPath".

One way to do this is by adding a file named Directory.Build.props into your solution directory with values like this

```
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <BaseIntermediateOutputPath>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)/../obj/</BaseIntermediateOutputPath>
    <BaseOutputPath>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)/../bin/</BaseOutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

For more details on how to do this, see http://www.natemcmaster.com/blog/2017/11/13/dotnet-watch-and-docker/

Comment: Thank you so much, I had pretty much given up on getting this worked out.